# WCF Basics - Endpoints

Tags: wcf

I'm wondering about the address="" section in the web.config file

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="user">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ptUserAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IUser" />
  </service>
</services>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="controller">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ptUserAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Icontroller" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I'm adding a second service that I will be calling via jQuery.  My first service worked great.  As you can see the endpoint address is blank.  I'm adding the second service and **I'm wondering first if I'm doing it correctly?**  *Can I create a new service tag using the same behaviorConfiguration, and binding but with a different contract?*

This spawned another question about the address in the web.config file.

**Why does it work when it is = "" and why would I want to use an address?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work with `address=""` when

- you host your service in IIS and basically IIS's virtual directory dictates the URL of your service (the vdir where your `*.svc` file exists). Thus if you have two separate services, with two separate `*.svc` files, then each entry in the configuration can have an `address=""` setting. But you **cannot** have two endpoints for the same service and both have the empty address attribute

or:

- you have a base address defined for your service in your config and thus that endpoint will use that base address for its service address

Comment: marc_s - Thank you for that clear answer.  Just for clarification, right now the service I'm working with is local and from your answer that is why I'm able to have the endpoint address = "".  When I move this to my shared server would it still work with the address = "" or will I have to change it to http://www.domain.com/services/service.svc

Comment: @JeffV: as long as you host it inside IIS on your shared server - you still can have the `address=""` since IIS and the virtual directory where the `*.svc` file exists determines the service address